# I want to add a custom field in a specific post page and output the content in woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress

Implemented a page post.php where products of woocommerce can post, and added custom fields using wp_editor functions. However, I do not know how to display the input result under the category or tag of woocommerce. How did you build it?
Thank you

post.php:

```
<form class="edit-form" role="form" method="post">
<?php wp_editor($post_rains,'post_rains',
array('editor_height' =>50,'quicktags'=>false,'media_buttons'=>false,'teeny' =>true,'editor_class'=>'post_rains'));?>
```

functions.php:

```
function add_text_below_meta(){
 // echo the content from the wp_editor here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slightly wrong, your first parameter is blank in the 'wp_editor' function, which is wrong, the code in the bracket cannot be blank, give the value and that will print in your frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
It was fixed because some code was wrong. But I do not know the code to write to functions.php
Thank you